# Dig not returning authority section?

Tags: terminal, dns

Digging wikipedia.com, on my Macbook Pro, returns:

```
$ dig wikipedia.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> wikipedia.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 40153
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;wikipedia.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
wikipedia.com.      1960    IN  A   208.80.152.201

;; Query time: 15 msec
;; SERVER: 75.75.75.75#53(75.75.75.75)
;; WHEN: Sun Jan 27 14:52:21 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 47
```

I could swear, last week my computer returned an `AUTHORITY SECTION` + some additional sections.

Now, whenever I `dig` any site, I'm not getting the `AUTHORITY SECTION`.

I feel like something is broken, but I'm not sure what it is (if anything) and how to fix it.

Another example:

```
$ dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 42853
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 11, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     137 IN  A   173.194.33.9
google.com.     137 IN  A   173.194.33.7
google.com.     137 IN  A   173.194.33.14
google.com.     137 IN  A   173.194.33.3
google.com.     137 IN  A   173.194.33.2
google.com.     137 IN  A   173.194.33.5
google.com.     137 IN  A   173.194.33.6
google.com.     137 IN  A   173.194.33.0
google.com.     137 IN  A   173.194.33.4
google.com.     137 IN  A   173.194.33.8
google.com.     137 IN  A   173.194.33.1

;; Query time: 43 msec
;; SERVER: 75.75.75.75#53(75.75.75.75)
;; WHEN: Sun Jan 27 14:56:45 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 204
```

Last week, I'm pretty sure I was getting an `AUTHORITY SECTION` as well.

Any tips? Did I accidentally set a flag to limit what `dig` returns on my machine? If so, how I can revert back to showing everything?

Here's what I get when digging from my work computer:

```
$ dig wikipedia.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> wikipedia.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5271
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;wikipedia.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
wikipedia.com.      3600    IN  A   208.80.152.201

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
wikipedia.com.      157415  IN  NS  ns0.wikimedia.org.
wikipedia.com.      157415  IN  NS  ns2.wikimedia.org.
wikipedia.com.      157415  IN  NS  ns1.wikimedia.org.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns0.wikimedia.org.  1684    IN  A   208.80.152.130
ns1.wikimedia.org.  1684    IN  A   208.80.152.142
ns2.wikimedia.org.  1684    IN  A   91.198.174.4

;; Query time: 127 msec
;; SERVER: 192.9.200.116#53(192.9.200.116)
;; WHEN: Mon Jan 28 13:51:57 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 162
```

... and:

```
$ dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 62316
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 11, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 4

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     300 IN  A   173.194.33.6
google.com.     300 IN  A   173.194.33.7
google.com.     300 IN  A   173.194.33.8
google.com.     300 IN  A   173.194.33.9
google.com.     300 IN  A   173.194.33.14
google.com.     300 IN  A   173.194.33.0
google.com.     300 IN  A   173.194.33.1
google.com.     300 IN  A   173.194.33.2
google.com.     300 IN  A   173.194.33.3
google.com.     300 IN  A   173.194.33.4
google.com.     300 IN  A   173.194.33.5

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.     344693  IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
google.com.     344693  IN  NS  ns2.google.com.
google.com.     344693  IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
google.com.     344693  IN  NS  ns4.google.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.google.com.     344797  IN  A   216.239.32.10
ns2.google.com.     344797  IN  A   216.239.34.10
ns3.google.com.     344797  IN  A   216.239.36.10
ns4.google.com.     344797  IN  A   216.239.38.10

;; Query time: 20 msec
;; SERVER: 192.9.200.119#53(192.9.200.119)
;; WHEN: Mon Jan 28 13:53:34 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 340
```

A part of me wonders if my home ISP (Comcast) or router is blocking something? Or, is my Mac at home set up differently than my Mac at work? Not sure how to test these theories.

Also, I could be mistaken that I ever did have `dig` working on my home laptop (I just don't remember for sure). Either way, I'm getting the results I want from my work Mac, and not from my laptop/home Mac. Why would the two differ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can not get authority section if you don't query on authoritative servers.

For example authoritative servers for the google.com are;

```
dig @l.gtld-servers.net google.com
```

Result will include these lines;

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns2.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns4.google.com.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107097/discussion-on-answer-by-tolginho-dig-not-returning-authority-section).

Answer (score 6):

Hmmm. Not too sure if it is a flag issue, but why not do this; SOA means “Start Of Authority”:

```
dig SOA wikipedia.com
```

My results:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> SOA wikipedia.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20716
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;wikipedia.com.         IN  SOA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
wikipedia.com.      86400   IN  SOA ns0.wikimedia.org. hostmaster.wikimedia.org. 2012060714 43200 7200 1209600 3600

;; Query time: 321 msec
;; SERVER: 208.67.222.222#53(208.67.222.222)
;; WHEN: Sun Jan 27 22:25:21 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 95
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107098/discussion-on-answer-by-jakegould-dig-not-returning-authority-section).

Answer (score 4):

> Not sure what exactly happened to all DNS servers

I assume they changed bind from version 9.11 to 9.12 
Somewhere the option "minimal-responses" changed from default "no" to "yes". 
If you define

> minimal-responses no ;

in the options section it will work as before.

Comment: That's was what I was looking for - BIND 9.16.1-Ubuntu! Thanks.
I added this line to `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` on Ubuntu. Local domains show the correct additional section now.
However, additional sections for external domains look weird in comparison with the answer from the public recursive servers. Probably, BIND needs some proper setup. Dunno how.

Answer (score 3):

This has been driving me crazy on my macbook too. So I dug a little deeper.
Not sure what exactly happened to all DNS servers, but a majority of them do not return 'authority' section anymore. Even with +authority flag. And neither for +additional.

But I knew webdig still worked for some. So tried webdig.

http://digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=google.com&type=&showcommand=on&colorize=on&useresolver=8.8.4.4&ns=all&nameservers=

I have saved the results on my pc to prove I am not crazy. But you can see yourself, that only a few DNS servers return the authority section at the moment.

`dig xxxxxxx.xx NS` still works and gets you the name servers in answers section. But no more authority section.

If you confirm the same, that would tell me I am not dreaming this.
Ashish

Answer (score -2):

Try ***soa*** like

**dig soa xxx.xxxxx.xxx**

or

**host soa xxx.xxxxx.xxx**

check this link it explains it

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-dns-domain-start-of-authority-record/